# How could I get URL of category image in MAGENTO SOAP API Call?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have been trying to get Category Image through magento SOAP API.
When I access to catalog_category.info method, it passes just image name, not URL of image.

How could I get FULL URL of category image using SOAP API Call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Categories images are in the folder magentohost/magento/media/catalog/category/
so the FULL url is magentohost/media/catalog/category/image_name

Comment: What should be the api call?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone would like to find out the location on their specific Magento install - assuming you know the image file name - go to the terminal and use the command `locate [file-name]`.
It should return the full path of the image location.
Mine was `[magento-root-dir]/pub/media/catalog/category/[file-name]`
I hope that helps. Cheers!